# ConstraintLayout и DialogFragment

Tags: android

Хочу использовать `Vertical Guideline` из `ConstraintLayout`, но возникает проблема(скриншоты прилагаю). такое возникает только с `DialogFragment`. Макеты для `Activity` исправно слушаются.

Как выглядит в Preview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выглядит на телефоне

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данной разметке вам вообще не нужны опорные линии (guidline). Связывайте элементы вертикально между собой, указываете маржины (отступы) где это необходимо:

[image: scr]

`Spinner` центруется к `EditText` таким образом. Верхняя точка спиннера с верхней точкой поля ввода, нижняя с нижней, получаем, что они на одной линии:

[image: scr]

три кнопки связываются через цепочки (chains): выделяете все три кнопки и в контекстном меню выбираете *"Center Horizontaly"*. Между кнопками появится связь в виде цепи и значки звеньев в пиктограммах. Это разместит кнопки равномерно по горизонтали.

В итоге получим следующее:

[image: scr]

код разметки *fragment_dialog.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="Новая запись"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="сумма"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Отмена"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Новая\nкатегория"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="ок"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

PS: чтобы вывести диалог без заголовка (пустое пространство наверху при использовании собственной разметки), указываем ему атрибут `STYLE_NO_TITLE`:

```
    MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();
    myDialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
    myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialog");
```

Сам диалог выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment  {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: А как мне поделить расстояние между EditText и Spinner?

Comment: Всё таки поделил `Guideline`ом EditText и Spinner :D
А вообще есть информация каким образом он отрезает куски из макета и как преобразует в диалог? А то у меня чаще всего получается танцы с бубном.

Comment: @Ivan никаким образом не отрезает куски из макета и никак не преобразует. Разметка берется целиком, как и для активити, просто размещается в меньшем окошке. Считайте, что размер окна диалога это и  есть весь экран активити (так оно и есть, просто активити не на весь экран растянута). Ширина и высота этого окошка  складывается из собственных размеров виджетов и маржинов между ними, но не более ~90% размера экрана. Ничего особенно специального для разметки диалога делать не нужно, она верстается как и для активити, как вы видите в приведенном в ответе примере

Comment: проблема с вашей разметкой в вопросе видимо в том, что между виджетами не установлены связи (не соедены точки на гранях виджетов), поэтому они в кучу. Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642642/177345) для подробностей

Comment: в моей разметке `EditText` занимает все свободное место (ширина - 0dp и  [размер "пилой"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532100/177345) в квадрате справа от превью), которое останется от минимально необходимого спиннеру (wrap_content, размер в квадрате справа от превью "галочками") + маржины между виджетами

Comment: да, проблема была в том, что `Spinner` не был соединён с заголовком и поэтому он просто не знал что с ним делать. Иногда кстати замечал такую вещь, если всё размещать с помощью dpi (например заголовок 300dp) и включить клавиатуру, то диалог начинал дрожать влево вправо с невероятной скоростью.

Comment: В разметке строго не рекомендуется использовать абсолютные размеры (заданные конкретным числом, как 300dp), так как из-за этого на разных размерах  экранов разметка будет выглядеть по другому.

Comment: можно [эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/company/livetyping/blog/302106/) на русском почитать по основам верстки в этом layout

Comment: Я это видел и плакать хотелось от вида франкенштейна которого я делал, а что с этим делать не знал. Спасибо, что помогли, хоть по человечески теперь выглядеть стало всё.

Comment: Эту статью вы мне кидали в предыдущем вопросе, спасибо)