# ConstraintLayout: поля на телефоне выходят за пределы экрана

Tags: java, android, xml

Всем привет! Пытаюсь создать приложение для Android. Код в ActivityMain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.andriy.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/start_button"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/settings_button"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/history_button"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/exit_button"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Код в визуальном редакторе:
 [image: Код в визуальном редакторе]
Код на физическом девайсе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему кнопки (или шаблон) вылазят за пределы экрана, и как это исправить? Я новичок. Я пытался гуглить, но ничего не нашел. Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Comment: Ширину 368dp автоматически подставила Студия вместо match_parent.

Comment: У вас не установлены констрайнты (связи) с боками экрана, вместо фиксированного значения ширины установите 0dp (аналог match_parent в констрайнт) , а правый край (точку справа, которая станет зеленой) соедените с краем экрана, так же и левый край для всех кнопок.

Comment: примеры верстки: [первый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532100/177345), [второй](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642642/177345), [третий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/654623/177345)

Comment: Спасибо! Установление связей с боками экрана помогло.