# Виджет на устройстве распологается в верхнем левом углу экрана, а не как в превью

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

Здравствуйте! Очень "нубовая" проблема. Делаю я тут свой "Hello world", вешаю кнопку по нажатию на которую должен появляться текст. Запускаю, а в конечном приложении расположение кнопки совсем иное, чем в разметке. Вопрос: "Что делать?". Прикрепляю скриншот.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642642/177345 - здесь позициционирование цепочкой, в конце общие гайды по работе и позиционированию  в ConstraintLayout. Общий смысл такой, что нужно не просто набросать виджеты на разметку, а установить между ними и краями экрана связи, которые как раз указывают, как виджеты расположены между собой и краями экрана (как это сделано для TextView). Без установленных связей виджет будет распологаться в верхнем левом углу экрана, что у вас и происходит.

Comment: Оформите код разметки в виде текста, а не скриншотом.

Comment: @pavlofff почему в превью по центру расположен?

Comment: потому что пространство имен tools явно указывает  абсолютные координаты для превью, но на устройстве то, что указано через tools, не отображается. О назначении tools можно почитать в офф. документации