# Как сделать так что бы горизонтальный список кнопок масштабировался под разные экраны?

Tags: android, android-studio, gui

Сделал фрагмент на котором расположены горизонтально 4 кнопки, в виде меню.
выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="86dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:text="button1"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="86dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:text="button2"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="86dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:text="button3"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="86dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:text="button4"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Запускаю эмулятор и вижу такую картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так что бы она на разных экранах были в один ряд?

Comment: Вам принципиально в констрэинте? Если да - гуглите как веса проставить кнопкам. Либо оберните конпки в `LinearLayout` и проставьте им вес в 1 через атрибут `android:layout_weight`

Comment: Не веса, а [цепочки (chains)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642642/177345)

Comment: @pavlofff я сделал цепочку, теперь в габаритах экрана но кнопки прижаты друг к другу без зазоров, хотя я им выставил android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"; android:layout_marginRight="2dp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для размещения нескольких виджетов в цепочку (chains) в `ConstraintLayout` если их собственная ширина (`wrap_content`) не позволяет уместить их с отступами, ширину виджетов нужно указать `match_constraint` (в визуальном редакторе AS 3, на разметке это соответствует значению *0dp*), тогда виджеты разделят пространство поровну.

Если какие то из виджетов должны иметь размер, отличный от остальных (например, одна из кнопок имеет большую ширину), то виджетам так же необходимо дополнительно указать параметр `layout_constraintHorizontal_weight`, который укажет размер виджета относительно других в цепочке (например, если все виджеты в цепочке имеют constraint weight = 1, а один из них = 2, то этот виджет будет в два раза шире остальных).

[Документация](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain) по этому вопросу (пункт 3).

Пример:

[image: scrn]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="кн1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="кн2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="кр3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button12"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="кн4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button11" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="кн5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button12" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

PS: указывать виджетам размер в абсолютных значениях (как `android:layout_width="86dp"`) - плохая практика, так как такая разметка будет иметь разный вид на устройствах с разной плотностью пикселей экрана и такая разметка будет не универсальной. Рекомендуется использовать `wpap_content`, `match_parent` и тд. атрибуты адаптивной верстки.

PPS: Сетка виджетов в Android принята равной *8dp*, то есть все размеры виджетов и отступов должны быть кратны 8 для правильного визуального восприятия. Например размер виджета по вертикали может быть равным 48dp (устанавливается автоматически через `wrap_content` для большинства виджетов), но никак не 50dp.

Comment: У меня они почему то собрались в одну кучу.

Comment: @SergeiR Даже если скопировать разметку в примере? версия ConstrainLayout последняя (1.0.2)?

Comment: В моем примере в этом месте ошибка была app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button12"