# Кнопки приложения. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте. Сегодня столкнулся с такой проблемой: В android studio, в дизайнере приложение выглядит нормально, кнопки отдельны друг от друга, но При отладке приложения все элементы собираются в одну кучу. Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите xml файл лейаута. Добавьте в вопрос. Скорее всего не выставлены констрейнты и студия вас предупреждает, что так будет, а вы не видите.

Comment: смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642642/177345), что вам делать, а вообще вам нужно читать по разработке, а не пытаться что то "напрограммировать" методом тыка - это не так работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятнее всего Вы используете RelativeLayout, а позиционирование элементов неправильное. В XML файле замените RelativeLayout на LinearLayout и уже станет лучше.

Comment: сейчас в студии по умолчанию ConstraintLayout, но мысль верная, только ее не мешает развить.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас по умолчанию в АС идет Constraint Layout. "Набросав" в этот макет элементов, вы все равно должны для каждого из них выставить constraints - ограничения.

Это можно сделать руками, выбрав вкладку Text и задав их самостоятельно в коде xml-файла. Также это можно сделать, выставляя для каждого элемента ограничения в находящейся справа панели атрибутов (стрелочка №1). В этом поможет опция отображения макета Design+Blueprint (выбираем в выпадающем списке где стрелочка №2) - при этом в схеме (блюпринте) отображаются не только используемые вами элементы, но и наложенные на них ограничения.

Однако эти два способа подходят для опытных. Если вы новичок в андроид-разработке, то после того, как создали макет, нажмите кнопочку Infer Constraints (стрелочка №3) - и АС сама выставит ограничения, которые вы потом при желании можете подредактировать для каждого элемента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]