# Элементы активити не на своих местах

Tags: android-studio

В Андроид Студио сбилдил файл  debug.апк, но в нем кнопка и текстовые поля не на своих местах, а в левом верхнем углу друг на друге. Хотя в конструкторе ИДЕ все отображается правильно и ХМЛ файлы вроде с правильными полями.
Объясните плиз отчего такое может быть? Заранее спасибо!!!

```
    введите сю  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.alexerjavagmail.mycalc.MainActivityCalc">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Num1"
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="первое число"
        android:inputType="number"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="182dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Num2"
        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="второе число"
        android:inputType="number"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="37dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="288dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id``/result"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:text=" 0 "
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="79dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="73dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="397dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>да код
```

Comment: Раскидать виджеты по экрану в IDE не достаточно для того, чтобы все работало. Затем их нужно связать между собой и краями экрана, установить между ними констрайнты, которые и укажут, как именно виджеты располагаются друг  относительно друга и краев экрана. Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642642/177345), как пример и в конце там есть ссылки, как правильно работать с этим контейнером, чтобы получить ожидаемый результат