# Проблема с отображением элементов в Android Studio

Tags: android

В приложении в эмуляторе неверно отображаются элементы как ImageButton и тд. При этом в content_main и activity_main все отображается как надо.[image: пример]

Comment: У тебя контейнером является ConstraintLayout, значит нужно задать связи для всех вложенных элементов

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642642/177345